# AngularJS: How to add label from checkbox to div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I send the text from selected `checkbox` to the `div` with `selected-checkbox` class?

For example, if I click on the first `checkbox` the `div` should get the text "First label".

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8jauzmtm/1/)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<label>First label</label>
<input type="checkbox" />

<label>Second label</label>
<input type="checkbox" />

<label>Third label</label>
<input type="checkbox" />

<div class="selected-checkbox"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated a fiddle. Please use below link
    https://jsfiddle.net/itsramesh/8jauzmtm/4/

Using angular `ng-true-value` attribute directive for checkboxes you can set label name to div.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
<script> 
angular.module('myApp',[]);
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('MyController',function($scope){
$scope.obj={};
})
</script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
<label>First label</label>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="obj.first" ng-true-value="First label" ng-false-value=""/>

<label>Second label</label>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="obj.first" ng-true-value="Second label" ng-false-value=""/>

<label>Third label</label>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="obj.first" ng-true-value="Third label" ng-false-value=""/>

<div class="{{obj.first}}">{{obj.first}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="{{obj.first}}">{{obj.first}}</div>// added for your reference inbetween div {{obj.first}}

Comment: It is checkbox group, selected only one checkbox at a time

Comment: if you want to multiple just change ng-model name